# Grails spring-security-rest authentication denied: Dynamic method get<Artefact>Class(artefactName)

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, grails

I've been working with Grails for around a month now, and we're currently working with angular, as such we've decided to take the REST approach with token based authentication.

Unfortunately whilst working with the plugin, I'm getting an issue that I've so far been unable to fix, the error I'm receiving whilst attempting to authenticate via a POST:

```
Object {email: "test@test.test", password: "TEST"}
```

The exception:

```
2014-11-17 15:25:29,509 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG credentials.DefaultJsonPayloadCredentialsExtractor  - Extracted credentials from JSON payload. Username: test@test.test, password: [PROTECTED]
2014-11-17 15:25:29,518 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Trying to authenticate the request
2014-11-17 15:25:29,524 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2014-11-17 15:25:29,563 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG rest.RestAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication failed: Dynamic method get<Artefact>Class(artefactName) requires a single String parameter
```

I'd like to note that I'm not using the default 'username' to login, but instead have changed it to 'email'. This is reflected in my config below:

Spring security part of Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   '/**':               ['permitAll'],
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.authoritiesPropertyName = 'roles'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = "/webapi/user/login"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = "/webapi/user/logout"
```

This line suggests that the issue is due to the REST plugin calling the wrong function, or am I wrong? I've checked all the versions - I'm using the exact same Grails, Spring-Core and Spring-Rest versions:

```
Dynamic method get<Artefact>Class(artefactName) requires a single String parameter
```

Thanks!

Comment: not probably related to your problem but you have the failureStatusCode setting in there twice

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and noticing that one, unfortunately doesn't fix the issue!

Comment: I notice the GormTokenStorageService store method expects a principal object with a username property. where maybe it should be principal."${usernamePropertyName}" instead. Just curious if you have tried sending the credentials with username instead of email

Comment: Well that's the idea behind
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'email'

Comment: I understand the point of the settings. I was simply wondering what the result is if, all settings as you had them, you sent a json object like `{username: "test@test.test", password: "TEST"}`. It may give a clue as to how to solve it.

Comment: nevermind my suggestion above to try username in place of email is a bad idea.

Comment: Is that your complete Config for Spring Security stuff? You're not defining a `grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName` which could result in a call to `DefaultGrailsApplication.getDomainClass(*null*)` which would result in the error you are seeing

Comment: Agreed with @Poundex question. Also I'd like to know which versions of Spring Security are you using.

Comment: Poundex fixed it for me! Thanks for catching that, it's all a little overwhelming when you first start out with all these configs! Submit it as an answer and I can accept if you like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is that your complete Config for Spring Security stuff? You're not defining a grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName which could result in a call to DefaultGrailsApplication.getDomainClass(*null*) which would result in the error you are seeing

- Poundex